# How to change the link color in a specific class for a div CSS

Tags: css, class, colors, hyperlink, hover

In my Page the following CSS is set:

```
a:link {
    color: #0094DE;
    text-decoration: none;


}
a:visited {
        text-decoration: none;
color: #0094DE;

}
a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
color: #DD127B;

}
```

I want to Change the Link color inside a div which has a class assigned to it.
I tried the following :

```
register:link{color:#FFFFFF;
        }
```

Where register is the name of the div in which i want to change the link color.
How can i do that?
Also  how to change the color for hover link over the same div?

Answer (score 62):

```
.register a:link{
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: note that this should be #register, not .register ... the OP said div not class

Comment: @Anthony The OP said div with a class assigned to it. Does what you say still apply?

Comment: OP: "Where register is the name of the div in which i want to change the link color" ... which to me says register is the id value, not the name of a class that's been assigned to the div.

Comment: This answer doesn't work for multiple users. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/30296997/8314623 for a different solution.

Answer (score 53):

It can be something like this:

```
a.register:link { color:#FFF; text-decoration:none; font-weight:normal; }
a.register:visited { color: #FFF; text-decoration:none; font-weight:normal; }
a.register:hover { color: #FFF; text-decoration:underline; font-weight:normal; }
a.register:active { color: #FFF; text-decoration:none; font-weight:normal; }
```

Comment: The top voted answer did not work for me, but using this syntax did work. Voting for this one.

Comment: Same for me too. +1

Comment: This was the only syntax that worked for me as well.  Thanks so much!

Comment: @JenVander thanks for your motivation :) it helps a lot!

Comment: I can confirm I had the same problem with the top voted, this one worked immediately

Comment: You can replace those 4 lines with just one: `a.register { color: white; text-decoration: none; font-weight: normal;  }`, (or `.register a { ... }` to more closely match the question which specifies "inside a div which has a class assigned to it".

Answer (score 8):

I think there is a confusion about what the OP is actually asking.

This solution:

```
a.register:link {color:#FFF}
```

...changes the color of a link whose class is "register". But that's not what the OP was asking.

And this solution:

```
.register a:link {color:#FFFFFF;}
```

...changes the color of a link that itself has no class but is placed inside of a div with class "register". And that's what the OP was asking.

Both of these answers are being upvoted here but only the second one is correct answer to the original question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Make sure you take a look at the other answers in the thread as well before submitting. It looks like this answer is the same as the current top voted but was determined to not be the final working solution.

Comment: Currently the most upvoted answer is correct and the second most upvoted answer is wrong but it's getting upvoted and praised anyway because it's correct for people who are trying to solve different problem than the OP posed. That's why I posted this to hopefully clear the confusion.

Answer (score 6):

how about something like this ...

```
a.register:link{
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: This is actually the problem I was trying to solve:  this places styling on something like this:

<a class="register">click me</a> 

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
#register a:link
{
color:#fffff;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add CSS on `a:hover` to not all the tag, but the some of the tag, best way to do that is by using class. Give the class to all the tags which you want to give style - see the example below.

```
<style>
a.change_hover_color:hover { 
    color: white !important;
}
</style>

<a class="change_hover_color">FACEBOOK</a>
<a class="change_hover_color">GOOGLE</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to put `a`, in front of `a:link` (`a`, `a:link`) in your CSS file. The only way I could get rid of that awful default blue link color. I'm not sure if this was necessary for earlier version of the browsers we have, because it's supposed to work without `a`

Answer (score -2):

smaller-size version:

```
#register a:link {color: #fff}
```