# CSS Menu with Hover

Tags: css

I am  trying to make my menu links `#666666` and then on `hover` make it `#FFFFFF`

i want these colours to change on the `text colour` and the `top border`

http://jsfiddle.net/4Xdkn/

```
#topbar {
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    background-color:#000000;
}
#topbar-inner {
    width:1000px;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
}
#logo {
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    margin-top:20px;
}

#menu {
    display:inline;
    float:right;
}
#menu > ul > li {
    display:inline-block;
    border-top:4px solid #666666;
    margin-right:20px;
    padding-top:20px;
    min-width:120px;
}
#menu > li {
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    margin-top:25px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
#menu > li:hover {
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: My mother always told me that `"want" is dead, even inside the king's garden` (i guess that this does not translate well in english, but still..)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the link color in a specific class for a div CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845517/how-to-change-the-link-color-in-a-specific-class-for-a-div-css)

Comment: From the look of your CSS, you should probably read this article. It will explain why you have this problem: [link](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selectors should be

```css
#menu li a {
    color: #666;
    display: block;
}
#menu li:hover {
    border-top-color: #FFF;
}
#menu li:hover a {
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

`#menu` has no direct `li` descendants so `#menu > li:hover` does not match anything.

http://jsfiddle.net/4Xdkn/8/

Comment: Wow, so many answers. But you were the first. Congrats! (I can delete my updated fiddle now.)

Comment: This solution has an issue, when you hover on the `li` it changes the colour and background, but you're not able to click on it, as the `a` tag is not set to `display:block`, personally I don't think this is the best solution.

Comment: excellent - thank you. how can i make the text colour #666666 when its not hovered over?

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your CSS

`#menu > li` does not target anything, since `#menu` is applied to a `div` and it has no direct children of type `li`.

Use these rules

```
#menu li {
    display:inline-block;
    border-top:4px solid #666666;
    margin-right:20px;
    padding-top:20px;
    min-width:120px;
}
#menu li:hover, 
#menu li:hover a {
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
#menu li a {
    color:#666666;
}
#menu li:hover {
    border-color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/4Xdkn/4/

Answer (score 1):

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nickr/4Xdkn/3/)

You need to add:

```
#menu li a {
     display:block; 
     padding-top:25px;   
     border-top:4px solid #666666;
 }
#menu 
     li a:hover { 
      border-color:red; 
      color:#fff
 }
```

On `#menu > ul > li` remove the `border-top` and `padding`, because this has been added to the `a` tag now.

On `#menu > li` remove the `margin-top` property

Answer (score 0):

Try the below css

```
       #topbar {
     width:100%;
     height:80px;
     background-color:#000000;
        }
       #topbar-inner {
     width:1000px;
     margin:0 auto 0 auto;
        }
       #logo {
     display:inline;
     float:left;
     margin-top:20px;
        }

      #menu {
     display:inline;
     float:right;
            }
       #menu > ul > li {
       display:inline-block;    
       margin-right:20px;   
       min-width:120px;
            }
       #menu > li { 
       list-style:none;
       padding:25px 0 0 0;
       margin-left:auto;
       margin-right:auto;
           border-top:1px solid #fff;
           }
        #menu ul li a:hover {
        color:#FFFFFF;
           }
       #menu li a {display:block; padding:20px 0 0 0;border-top:4px solid #666666;}
       #menu li a:hover { border-top:4px solid #fff; color:#fff}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/4Xdkn/7/

```
#topbar {
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    background-color:#000000;
}
#topbar-inner {
    width:1000px;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
}
#logo {
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    margin-top:20px;
}

#menu {
    display:inline;
    float:right;
}
#menu > ul > li {
    display:inline-block;
    border-top:4px solid #666666;
    margin-right:20px;
    padding-top:20px;
color:#ffffff;
    min-width:120px;
}
#menu > li > a {
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    margin-top:25px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
     text-decoration:none;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#menu li:hover {
    color:#FFFFFF !important;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-top:4px solid #ffffff;
    display:inline-block;
}
#menu li a:hover{
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Colorize the a-element instead of the li and make the a element as big as the li.

```
#menu li a:hover {
    color:white;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width: 1px 0px 0px 0px;
    border-color:white;
}
```