# Changing color of link using class in css

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I'm trying to change the color of a link to green with class, in css, but it's not working for some reason. What am I doing wrong?

```css
a:link {
color: red;
}
.colorGreen a:link {
color: green;
}
```

```html
<a href = 'www.link.com'> www.link.com </a> <br>
<a href = 'www.link.com'> www.link.com </a> <br>
<a class = 'colorGreen' href = 'www.link.com'> www.link.com </a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting the children `a tags` which have parent class `colorGreen`. It should be:

```
a.colorGreen:link {
   color: green;
}
```

Now, you're selecting the `a tag` which have `colorGreen` class.

Comment: I got the wrong answer from here, that got up voted 21 times. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845517/how-to-change-the-link-color-in-a-specific-class-for-a-div-css

Comment: @jessica your question isn't the same as that one

Comment: @jessica There's nothing wrong. There the OP is selecting a tag which have parent class `register`.

Comment: This answer says exactly what the other answer says but solves a different problem, and both are correct. It deserves the check. https://jsfiddle.net/s1owjz21/ +1

Comment: Yeah. I don't get the difference between the 2 questions. Isn't the other question also about setting classes on links?

Comment: @jessica I am clearly stating you that there the OP is trying to select the a tag which have parent class `register` but here you are trying to select the a tag which have `colorGreen` class. Didn't you get it?

Comment: So, the other person is trying to set the color of the link through the parent div, and I'm trying to set the color of the link through the link itself?

Comment: @jessica Yes, glad you got it.

Answer (score 1):

css is use when

```
  .classname a:link{
    }
```

element is

```
<div class="classname">
<a ></a>
</div>
```

```css
a:link {
color: red;
}
.colorGreen:link {
color: green;
}

.colorBlue a:link {
color: Blue;
}
```

```html
<a href = 'www.link.com'> www.link.com </a> <br>
<a href = 'www.link.com'> www.link.com </a> <br>
<a class = 'colorGreen' href = 'www.link.com'> www.link.com </a>


<div class="colorBlue">  
  <a href = 'www.blue.com'> www.link.com </a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use many ways to apply this. Using `!important`

```css
a:link {
color: red;
}
.colorGreen {
color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<a href = 'www.link.com'> www.link.com </a> <br>
<a href = 'www.link.com'> www.link.com </a> <br>
<a class = 'colorGreen' href = 'www.link.com'> www.link.com </a>
```

or this way.

```css
 a:link {
    color: red;
}
.colorGreen:link {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
   


    <a href = 'www.link.com'> www.link.com </a> <br>
    <a href = 'www.link.com'> www.link.com </a> <br>
    <a class = 'colorGreen' href = 'www.link.com'> www.link.com </a>
```

Comment: Using `!important` is almost always the wrong advice.

Comment: Thanks for informing me,