# Change color of link using css

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

How to change color of Cssclass for a link? I want to change the color of the link once the classes for the semester are full. The color of the link is blue but when the class is full of students I want the color to be changed to purple.
In my site.css the css class is:

```
.sem-color-purple{
    color:#800080
).
```

In the code behind cs file it is stated as:

```
// Purple text indicates classes are full for the semester
hlSemester.CssClass = "sem-color-purple";
```

Comment: Are you disabling the link?

Comment: How are you generating the links? Are you using data binding? Can we see the markup?

Comment: can you show the rendered html please

Comment: Assuming you're using razor, refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11785166/conditionally-change-css-class-in-razor-view/11785554

Comment: No the link does not get disabled. the link of the color needs to be purple once the classes are full

Comment: @sam_ferree looks more like aspx rather than razor (from the tags)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the link color in a specific class for a div CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845517/how-to-change-the-link-color-in-a-specific-class-for-a-div-css)

Comment: Yes razor is not used it is the aspx code

Comment: Tried the solution given for Possible duplicate of How to change the link color in a specific class for a div CSS – d219 did not work

Comment: Is the class actually getting added to the link?

Comment: Also, in your example you have a ')' instead of '}' in your css for the sem-color-purple.

Comment: yes the class is getting added to the link.

Comment: .sem-color-purple{
    color:#800080
}.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)